# Is it possible to have pretty URLs with Livewire 3 wire:model.live?

Tags: laravel-livewire

I want a Livewire component using wire:model.live to update the URLs without using query parameters, just like:
"/category/fruit" instead of "/?category=fruit"

I have this routes:

```
Route::get('/', ShowProducts::class)->name('products');
Route::get('/category/{keywordSlug}', ShowProducts::class)->name('products');
```

I have this component:

```
namespace App\Livewire;
class ShowProducts extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    #[Url(as: 'category')]
    public $keywordSlug = '';

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.show-products', compact('products', 'webKeywords'));
    }
```

And this on the view:

```
<select wire:model.live="keywordSlug">
    <option value="">Any</option>
    @foreach ($webKeywords as $webKeyword)
        <option value="{{ $webKeyword->slug }}">{{ ucfirst($webKeyword->plural_name) }}.
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I can load this URL manually ant it works well: /category/fruit

But when I select an option on the select, Livewire updates current URL to this one: /?category=fruit

Is it possible to get Livewire using the first one?